# Unique image with more hover effects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to ask if it was possible, using only one image, to have more hover effects?
For example, a single image divided into columns and each column has its own effect, as if the image were divided into transparent areas.

Comment: Have you done any research on this yourself? Have you tried to write any code?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find anything that would explain the concept clearly

Comment: Yes it is posssible via CSS and HTML. What have you tried so far and for what kind of effects ?

Comment: Basically I have to divide a pool into lanes, and each lane should have its own popup message.
The problem is that every time I get a single popup.

Comment: you should show what you've done, so we see where it fails or if it's appropriate. from there you'll get answers or advise instead talks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.

```css
.x { opacity:0; cursor: pointer;}
  .x:hover { opacity:1; }
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
 <defs>
  <filter id="blur">
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8"/>
  </filter>
  <image href="https://i.imgur.com/Lky5aRQ.jpg" width="600" height="600" id="img"/>
  <clipPath id="c1">
   <path d="M0 0h100v600h-100z"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="c2">
   <path d="M100 0h100v600h-100z"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="c3">
   <path d="M200 0h100v600h-100z"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="c4">
   <path d="M300 0h100v600h-100z"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="c5">
   <path d="M400 0h100v600h-100z"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="c6">
   <path d="M500 0h100v600h-100z"/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
 <use xlink:href="#img"/>
 <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)" clip-path="url(#c1)" class="x"/>
 <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)" clip-path="url(#c2)" class="x"/>
 <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)" clip-path="url(#c3)" class="x"/>
 <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)" clip-path="url(#c4)" class="x"/>
 <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)" clip-path="url(#c5)" class="x"/>
 <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)" clip-path="url(#c6)" class="x"/>
</svg>
```

Thank you